# VB.Net - Read email even when Outlook is closed

Tags: vb.net, outlook, visual-studio-2017

Now I have the code below which executes even when Outlook is closed. What I would need is to be able to run this code every time a new email is received(with Outlook closed). What additions/changes would I make? Any sample code? Thanks

```
 Dim serverURI As New Uri("https://.....com/ews/exchange.asmx")
        Dim exch As New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService()
        exch.Url = serverURI
        exch.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        exch.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", 
                                                           "password", "domain")


        Dim iv As ItemView = New ItemView(999)
        iv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow
        Dim inboxItems As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = Nothing
        inboxItems = exch.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, iv)

        For Each i As Item In inboxItems
            MsgBox("this is" & i.Subject)
            Exit For
        Next
```

Comment: So, are you happy to rewrite a solution that doesn't use interop? Right now your solution uses Outlook, so it can't work without there being an instance of Outlook running

Comment: I would not mind that as long as it is not too complicated.  Actually, I now have the code below which executes even when Outlook is closed.  What I would need is to be able to run this code every time a new email is received(with Outlook closed). Thanks

Comment: I added the code in the edit above

Comment: It doesn't look like it conains any kind of eventing/notofication/messaging system that would experience something when a mail arrives?

Comment: assuming the data is sourced from office 365 outlook...you could use push notifications from the service, instead of from the client - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations ...its a server operation, rather than running on a client box

Comment: I have to get an email that a new email was received in my work Outlook Inbox. It is the classic Outlook, not on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = Nothing
    oApp = New Outlook.Application()
    Dim [nameSpace] As Outlook.[NameSpace] = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim items As Outlook.Items = Nothing

    Try
        [nameSpace].Logon("", "", False, Missing.Value)
        Dim folder = [nameSpace].Folders("xxx@xx.com").Folders("Inbox")
        items = folder.Items
        AddHandler items.ItemAdd, AddressOf Items_ItemAdd
        Console.WriteLine("yes")
    Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
        [nameSpace].Logon("", "", True, True)
    End Try
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Console.WriteLine("success")
    Dim myOlMItem As Outlook.MailItem
    myOlMItem = CType(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
    Console.WriteLine(myOlMItem.Subject)
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Is this to send me an email or notify me when a new email arrives in the Outlook inbox even when Outlook is closed?  That is what I would basically need. Thanks

Comment: When a new email arrives in the Outlook inbox, the code will print out the subject of the new email.

Comment: Yes, you could try it.